# some lectures/examples on Q-learning using feature/linear approximation

Tags: machine-learning, references, reinforcement-learning

Most of the resources that I find in the internet deal with Q-learning or SARSA in the discrete sense, when state spaces and actions are finite. There are variety of examples and tutorials for this case.

I am looking for the case when state space is infinite. In this case, it is impossible to list all the states. Hence, an important technique would be to make a features-based representation. However, the resources are few and far in between.

If you know of resources, websites, examples, lectures, even video lectures, especially on the Q-learning/SARSA with features-based representation, it be great to have a look.

Comment: The classic Sutton and Barto book talks a lot about state space approximation. It is available freely online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit weights into Q-values with linear function approximation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187110/how-to-fit-weights-into-q-values-with-linear-function-approximation)

Answer (score 1):

Georgia Tech has recently released a [reinforcement learning course](https://www.udacity.com/course/reinforcement-learning--ud600) that covers this in a section called "Generalization." See also Gordon's paper ["Stable function approximation in dynamic programming"](http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/), and Ladoukis & Parr's paper on [least-squares policy iteration](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume4/lagoudakis03a/lagoudakis03a.pdf).

You may also find value in the BURLAP continuous-domain [tutorials](http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/tutorials/scd/p1.html). ([BURLAP](http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/) is a Java library "for the use and development of single or multi-agent planning and learning algorithms and domains to accompany them.") In particular, the lunar lander example uses SARSA($\lambda$).